# retrofit Delete request changes to Get request in Android

Tags: android, retrofit, http-delete

I send a Delete request by retrofit but it results in Get request response.
it should return response code 204 but it returns 200 instead.

note: In postman it returns 204 but in android it returns 200

My request code is like below:

```
api.DeleteProduct("JWT " + token, productId, new Callback<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
    public void success(JsonObject jsonObject, Response response) {
        Log.e(TAG, "body "+response.getStatus());
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

    }
});
```

and its interface is like below:

```
@DELETE("/products/{productId}")
public void DeleteProduct(@Header("Authorization") String authorization, @Path("productId") String productId, Callback<JsonObject> callback);
```

Comment: from your java code every thing is alright. your server is likely not handling the web request well. Always be aware that http verbs like GET,POST,HEAD,PUT, etc are convention based i.e there is no strict rule to for a web server to respect those verbs. for eg on nodejs there is a module called method-override that can turn a post request to put etc. you can verify that you are sending a delete request by adding a logger to your retrofit rest adapter. you might want to remove this in production though.

Comment: I'm using postman for verifying server responses. i get 204 for Delete request and 200 for Get request. it seems that server is OK!!!

Comment: retrofit log is like this
—-> HTTP DELETE http://www.bafeh.com/product/fees/122
10-19 10:34:29.068 21317-22526/com.example.masoud.firstproject E/ProductInfo﹕ Authorization: ...
10-19 10:34:29.068 21317-22526/com.example.masoud.firstproject 
—-> END HTTP (no body)
10-19 10:34:29.798 21317-22526/com.example.masoud.firstproject 
<-— HTTP 200 http://www.bafeh.com/product/fees/122 (726ms)

Comment: if you have control over the server-side code check the code well.... you are actually getting 200 response from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Django framework wants a slash at the end of the url for patch and delete requests.